# Unable to Run Grails, error with resolving class

Tags: java, grails

I am fairly new to grails and need help figuring out why I cannot run grails due to this error below:

```
grails> run-app
| Running application...
startup failed:
C:\DIR\grails-inventory\grails-app\controllers\harbor\AssetController.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node.ParamsAction
 @ line 3, column 1.
import org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node.ParamsAction;
^
1 error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

If I were to comment out that particular line in AssetController, grails will execute however the whole application will have NullPointer errors

Comment: Are you sure that you have include `org.apache.jasper.compiler` as dependency? Could you show you gradle dependencies?

Comment: oh, no i havent done that. How do I add it though?   it's empty - dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
   
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this to Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies { 
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g. 
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    compile 'tomcat:jasper-compiler:5.5.9'
}
```

You can find jasper for Grails 2.x:https://grails.org/plugin/jasper and plugins for Grails 3.x are here: https://bintray.com/grails/plugins, but as I see there is no Jasper plugin for Grails 3, so try to add dependency directly as mentioned above.

Comment: as of now, I don't see Jasper in grails plugin list.  
| Grails Version: 3.1.1
| Groovy Version: 2.4.5
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_60

Comment: As I see from the code it is not a Grails plugin, you are using it as a simple lib. Are you using it as a plugin? What version of grails are you using?

Comment: trying to run an old project developed in 2.2.2 on a 3.1.2 environment. I am very confused as to how to do this, been trying for a while.

Comment: In a case of grails plugin is just a wrapper around some lib, so you do not search for grails plugin in most case, but could add directly to dependency  link. But you can find jasper for Grails 2.x:https://grails.org/plugin/jasper and plugins for Grails 3.x are here: https://bintray.com/grails/plugins

Comment: for the compile tomcat - ould not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
   > Could not resolve tomcat:jasper-compiler:5.5.23.
     Required by:
         grailsapp:grails-3.1.2:0.1
      > Could not resolve tomcat:jasper-compiler:5.5.23.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/tomcat/jasper-compiler/5.5.23/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/tomcat/jasper-compiler/5.5.23/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.pom'.

Comment: Try to use version 5.5.9

Comment: Could not resolve tomcat:jasper-compiler:5.5.9.
     Required by:
         grailsapp:grails-3.1.2:0.1     I think im missing something

Comment: Try to add to Maven repositories in project build.gradle.  Was your old project using Jasper plugin?  If yes.  Plugin has not been ported to 3.x yet.  In new project you need to change code and access Jasper using java.

Comment: @KriziaSimon seem like this error are caused by using old project with new Grails. Diffs between Grails 2.x and Grails 3.x are dramatical, so maybe it is worth to run project on original Grails 2.x.

Comment: Got the jasper to install, re compiled it a lot. however a lot of ORM mapping invalid came up. This question is officially solved though

Comment: Thank you to you both, specially @sphinks

Comment: So you just clean and compile project? Am I correct?

Comment: nope, really just recompiled it, stopped and recompiled grails alot